# Did I Do Something Wrong Answering My Own Question?

Tags: discussion

I was having an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31835986/2019162) that I couldn't figure out when trying to move to Visual Studio 2015. I had initially marked the first answerer as the answer, not expecting to nicely solve my issue with an actual solution. However, a couple days later I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997291/2019162) my own question, marked it as the new answer and got down voted for my trouble.

I feel that my answer was the best answer (so far) to the question I asked, so the downvote feels unfair (or even, possibly, spiteful). I didn't figure out the Roslyn internals of my question, since I don't have time, but I was able to rewrite the tests with minimal pain and move on with my life in VS 2015. Incidentally, I still have a 50 rep bounty to give out if anyone wants to dig into Roslyn and see what's up.

Do I need to change something for future questions?

Comment: We can't know why the one person that downvoted you choose to downvote you any more than you do.  We can't read minds.  There are any  number of reasons they could have felt that the answer was unhelpful.

Comment: Just wait, if your self accepted answer is more useful for future research, it will get upvoted over time.

Answer (score 13):

There's nothing wrong with answering your own question. However, worrying about every single downvote is bad form.

Comment: Joel posting a short answer to a tired, frequently-asked question doesn't seem like a good sign.

Comment: i heard you can get points

Comment: You need to redeem them first. [Learn about Unicoins.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins)

Comment: Points not valid on Meta sites or where prohibited by law.